# How do SubMenuset set the menu as radio button

Tags: android

I add two submenu items. When I set setCheckable(true), it changes CheckBox. How to set it as radio button?
It can only select one when click once, and display the icon then close the submenu.

```
settingMenu.add(1, SETTING_SECOND_ID, 0, R.string.menu_setting_second).setCheckable(true);  
settingMenu.add(1, SETTING_100MILLISECOND_ID, 1, R.string.menu_setting_100milisec).setCheckable(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the group to be [exclusively checkable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#setGroupCheckable%28int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29). In your case, the group is 1. Hence a call like

```
settingMenu.setGroupCheckable(1, true, true);
```

will do the magic.